We've taken/We took immediate steps
Suppose John goes to YouTube and notices that someone has uploaded his video without asking for his permission. He sends an email to the YouTube support team, asking them to delete the video because it violates copyright law. After complying with his request, they respond to his email with the following text:
1. Thank you for bringing this matter to our attention. We've taken immediate steps to address the situation and removed the video from our website. We've also conducted an internal review to make sure this doesn't happen again in the future. If you have any other concerns, please let us know.
2. Thank you for bringing this matter to our attention. We took immediate steps to address the situation and removed the video from our website. We also conducted an internal review to make sure this doesn't happen again in the future. If you have any other concerns, please let us know.
I made up the context and the text the YouTube support team sends to John. Version #1 is appropriate in this context, while version #2 isn't. Am I right? Thanks.

Both are acceptable. Present perfect sounds more formal, so it's often used in official communications like this.

...but the second might be preferable when describing steps they took when questioned later about their actions.

The context here indicates the author is clearly talking about something which has just happened.  In such situations, the present perfect should be used.

Since your question wants to know if #2 "isn't appropriate", the answer is yes, it is not appropriate, but only because the letter is pointing out not only that prompt action has been taken but is presumably also notifying the complainant promptly. The simple past would not express any sense that the notification is itself prompt.  The simple past is not ungrammatical, just not "appropriate", in the sense that if the goal is to create the sense of promptness in all regards, it doesn't do the job.  The present perfect does. Maybe  "not an apt choice" would be better than "inappropriate".

As both @WeatherVane and @BillyKerr have commented, the version with the progressive (“We’ve taken … We’ve also conducted…”) conveys the sense that their actions are still recent. The simple-past version (“We took … We also conducted…”) is more appropriate if those actions are seen as more remote in the past.
The matter of what counts as recent and what is longer ago here is completely subjective. There is no rule or bright line distinguishing the two cases.
